# Removing characters after a certain number of times

Tags: java

So essentially I am trying to delete any repetitions of a character after it has been found a certain number of times. So given a string and an integer for number of occurrences allowed delete it after that number has been reached.

For example: `DeleteChars("abaabbb",2);` should output: "abab"

I'm having trouble getting it to work exactly and I don't really know where I am going wrong. I feel like what I have should work though. But I am not very good with regex so I'm sure that is where the problem is occuring but, I don't really know how to fix it.

```
public static String DeleteChars(String data, int deleteValue)
{
    String regex = "(.)\\1{" + deleteValue + ",}";

    StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
    while(m.find())
    {
        m.appendReplacement(sbuffer, "");
    }
    m.appendTail(sbuffer);
    return sbuffer.toString();
}
```

Edit: Adding more cases for I/O to get desired output.

```
DeleteChars("ababababababa", 2);
Expected: abab

DeleteChars("abcabcaabbcceess", 1)
Expected: abces

DeleteChars("Hey there are spaces", 2)
Expected: Hey ther arspacs

DeleteChars("absdfsdfgldfj", 0)
Expected:
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are getting? Is it an error that the program throws or an output that you were not expecting?

Comment: *"But I am not very good with regex so I'm sure that is where the problem is occuring but, I don't really know how to fix it."* -  Have you tried debugging the code?   That's a much better idea than *guessing* what the problem is.

Comment: It returns an empty string.

Comment: A debugger will tell you more than that.   Set breakpoints, look at variables, watch what happens.

Comment: Also, I think the logic of your code is incorrect.  I actually think that this problem can't  be solved using regexes at all.

Comment: @StephenC is right. Regex is not a good (maybe wrong) approach. My bet is take advantage of HashMap

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regex in this case. You could [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) each character to and integer, which represents the number of occurrences in the string, then check if should be added or ignored (check comments on the code for more info).

### Snippet:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Snippet {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("output = " + DeleteChars("abaabbb", 2 ));
        System.out.println("output = " + DeleteChars("abcabcaabbcceess", 1));
        System.out.println("output = " + DeleteChars("Hey there are spaces", 2));
        System.out.println("output = " + DeleteChars("absdf\nsdf\ngld\nfj", 2));

    }
    
    public static String DeleteChars(String data, int deleteValue)
    {
        //map characters with Integers example {a=3, b=4}
        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
        //array of string data
        char[] strArray = data.toCharArray(); 
        //output (empty at first)
        String output = "";
        for (char c : strArray) { 
            if (charCountMap.containsKey(c)) { 
                // If char is present in charCountMap, 
                // incrementing it's count by 1 
                charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1); 
            } 
            else { 
                // If char is not present in charCountMap, 
                // putting this char to charCountMap with 1 as it's value 
                charCountMap.put(c, 1); 
            }
            //if not reached max ocurrences just add the char to output string
            if(charCountMap.get(c) <= deleteValue) output = output + c;
        } 
        //print map (just informative)
        System.out.println("Map = " + charCountMap.toString().replaceAll("\n","linebreak").replaceAll(" =", "space ="));
        return output;
    }
    
}
```

### Output:

```
Map = {a=3, b=4}
output = abab
Map = {a=4, b=4, c=4, s=2, e=2}
output = abces
Map = {space =3, p=1, a=2, r=2, s=2, c=1, t=1, e=5, H=1, h=1, y=1}
output = Hey ther arspacs
Map = {a=1, b=1, s=2, d=3, f=3, g=1, linebreak=3, j=1, l=1}
output = absdf
sdf
glj
```

It will match with your test cases, and also handles linesbreaks and spaces.

Comment: I just tested this out, it sort of works. However, I need this to work with any character, including spaces and line breaks. Are there any checks that need to be done for that?

Comment: This only works if the letters are next to each other as stated in the output of your second example. The output I want to expect would be: `abaabbcceedqwefff` I want to only allow that number of characters in the string as a whole if that makes sense. I don't care if they are next to each other or not. Can I use regex to do that or should I look for a different approach?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add examples of I/O so we can test it out please?

Comment: @Dtb49 check edited. I've covered your test cases with another approach

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that doesn't use regex, this option uses a hashmap to store the quantity of each character in the string. This will work will any string, not just alphabetical.

```
    public static String deleteChars(String data, int deleteValue) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> compareMap = new HashMap<>();
    String returnString = "";

    // Iterate through the string. Use a hashmap to store the number of characters in the string as you iterate
    // through. Add chars until you reach the limit.
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        char charToAdd = data.charAt(i);
        Integer numberOfChars = compareMap.get(charToAdd);
        Integer valueToAdd = (numberOfChars == null) ? 1 : numberOfChars+1;
        compareMap.put(charToAdd, valueToAdd);

        //After incrementing the hashmap value, we check to see if we can add this to the return string
        if (compareMap.get(charToAdd) <= deleteValue) {
            returnString = returnString.concat(String.valueOf(charToAdd));
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Does this work with all characters? How would it handle a line break?

Comment: @Dtb49 It retains the first deleteValue number of line breaks (\n)